# Creating a new Hibernate table

Tags: java, hibernate

So I'm still pretty new to Hibernate, and I'm working on a large-ish application that already has a database with several Hibernate tables.  I'm working on a new feature, which includes a new `@Entity` class, and I need these objects to be stored in a new table.  The class is declared like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DATA_REQUEST")
public class DataRequest {

//Some fields, nothing fancy

}
```

The `DATA_REQUEST` table does not exist, nor do I have any data to store in it yet.  I started the application up, expecting that it would either create the table or crash because it doesn't exist yet.  Neither of these actually happened.

So: do I need to create the table manually (easily done)?  Or do I need to go somewhere else to tell Hibernate that I need this table?  I've seen the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, which looks like a good place to start.

Comment: From what I remember, Hibernate will create the tables when needed (eg. when you save your first object), although I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify "create" for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property. Read more details [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html). This is not recommended in production but only for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

As for adding a new column to the table

- As long as it is **not a not null column** you don't need drop the table or restart your hibernate app
- If you do want to use the column then you need to map the column in the code/hbm file, so you will have to restart the hibernate app
- If there is no mapping present as far as hibernate is concerned the column does not exisist, If it is a not null column then underlying data base would reject inserts/updates as hibernate will not include the column in generated sql

Comment: "As long as it is not a not null column" -- that makes sense.  I kinda thought of that after I posted.  Do I map a column with the `@Column` annotation?

Comment: So I actually feel kinda bad that I made this two questions in one, so I moved the part you answered into a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650588/adding-columns-to-a-hibernate-table-with-data.  If you want to copy your answer over there, I'll accept it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

from hibernate documentation

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.
>   e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

[hibernate Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)