# Hibernate: Create new table from the deserialized entity

Tags: java, hibernate

As far as I know hibernate creates/checks tables on the startup. Is it possible to force it to create new table from the (for example) new deserialized entity or from any entity that was not present during the startup.
I don't know if there is any practical usage for this case (like when you don't want to reboot your service but you need to save into the new table).
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613513/creating-a-new-hibernate-table

Comment: As I wrote the question is not about how to create a table on the start of the application.